# C++ Get the substring between custom delimiters without the use of regex

Tags: c++, string, substring

I've a simple string of format:

```
"lorem ipsum <span id='1'>extract_me-1</span> dolor
sit amet <span id='2'>extract_me-2</span> adispicing consequit lorem ipsum
sit amet <span id='3'>extract_me-3</span> adispicing dolor lorem"
```

And now i need to **extract the strings between a custom delimiters specified**

for example,

```
Substring("<span id='1'>","</span>") = extract_me-1
Substring("<span id='2'>","</span>") = extract_me-2
Substring("lorem","<span id='1'>") = ipsum
Substring("extract_me-1","dolor") = </span>
```

I've accomplished this task using regex:

```
std::string str="lorem ipsum <span id='1'>extract_me-1</span> dolor sit amet <span id='2'>extract_me-2</span> adispicing consequit lorem ipsum sit amet <span id='3'>extract_me-3</span> adispicing dolor lorem";

std::smatch match;
std::regex rgx ("<span id='1'>(.*?)</span>");

if (regex_search(str, match, rgx)){
 //First substring
 std::cout<<match.str(1);
}
```

Is there any way to do this without the use of regex.. I've tried using `substr` a couple of times, but still no avail.. any help is highly appreciated, thnks

EDIT : the input `str` is not in a complete html format, just a bit of random tags.. and i just need the substring from start to **next closest end position** (yes, even when there is nested tags of same `span` or repetition)

Comment: [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) might come in handy.

Comment: Use a library to parse html instead of doing it badly yourself.

Comment: Just out of interest, if you have successfully done this with regex, why would you *need* a different way?

Comment: @AllanWind its only a few random tags and not a complete html.. regex gets this job done neatly, but including <regex> header adds another 1mb to the program

Comment: @paxdiablo its library size.. its just a few tags only and  couple of dudes told me its an overkill to include regex for a simpler job

Comment: That's pretty wild re 1mb size of regex.  It's would be sed 1-liner and sed, the binary, on my system is 122k :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using `.find` and `.substr`. It turned out to be easier than I thought

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int t1,t2;
string str="lorem ipsum <span id='1'>extract_me-1</span> dolor sit amet <span id='2'>extract_me-2</span> adispicing consequit lorem ipsum sit amet <span id='3'>extract_me-3</span> adispicing dolor lorem";

string subStrng(string start,string end);

int main() {
    string txt1 = subStrng("<span id='1'>","</span>");
    string txt2 = subStrng("<span id='2'>","</span>");
    string txt3 = subStrng("<span id='3'>","</span>");

    cout<<txt1<<"\n"<<txt2<<"\n"<<txt3;
    return 0;
}


//Substring func.
string subStrng(string start,string end){
    t1=str.find(start);
    if(t1 >= 0){
        // string 'start' exist in str.
        // Now, lets find the next closest string 'end'
        t1=t1+start.length();
        t2=str.find(end,t1);
        if(t2 >= 0){
            // next closest 'end' exists in the str.
            // Now, lets extract the substring in between
            return str.substr(t1,t2-t1);

        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: This will fail if you have a sub-span.   It will fail if id is unquoted or quoted with ".  Just wanted to let you know if you were not aware.  Also you changed the output format you expected from your question.

Comment: Its not a complete html to begin with (so no parser).. plus, there is no tag nesting scenario arises..And like the question title indicates, i just need to get the substring between custom delimiters without the use of regex. From the First start position to next closest end

Comment: You could have accepted my answer then, right?  At least upvote it.

Comment: @Allan wind i just simply need a substring between two delimiters.. your method searchs for the tag, then the id and then searchs for next ''<'' symbol. SO says to wait least 14 hours before accepting self posted answer

Comment: My solution  does that because you asked for the format: `txt1 = extract_me-1  
txt2 = extract_me-2  
txt3 = extract_me-3`.  You solution only display the span text (without the last trailing newline).  It's fine too, of course, but that is not want you asked for in your question.

Comment: Thank you lad, for future visitors, Imma do a bit of clarification in the question part again XD

Answer (score 1):

You need to check each return value of each of the `str.find()` calls like I do for the first one but this is the gist of it.  Might want to just search for the tag, then the id, but then you also need to check for non-existing id for for that tag:

```
#include <string>


int main() {
    const std::string str="lorem ipsum <span id='1'>extract_me-1</span> dolor sit amet <span id='2'>extract_me-2</span> adispicing consequit lorem ipsum sit amet <span id='3'>extract_me-3</span> adispicing dolor lorem";
    const std::string tag = "<span id='";
    std::string r = "";
    for(size_t pos = 0;;) {
        size_t tag_pos = str.find(tag, pos);
        if(tag_pos  == str.npos) {
            break;
        }
        size_t id_pos = tag_pos + tag.size();
        size_t id_pos2 = str.find("'", id_pos);
        size_t txt_pos = str.find(">", id_pos2) + 1;
        size_t txt_pos2 = str.find("<", txt_pos);

        r += "txt";
        r += str.substr(id_pos, id_pos2 - id_pos);
        r += " = ";
        r += str.substr(txt_pos, txt_pos2 - txt_pos);
        r += "\n";

        pos = txt_pos2;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice work dude.. but just a tiny bit of problem, this fails if the substring contains special characters such as ```<```  or ```>```

Comment: @A5H1Q: The regex in your question also fails to handle nesting correctly.  As does your answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt how? it would be helpful if you explain a bit

Comment: @A5H1Q: If the input is `<span id='1'>extract_<span style="color: red">me</span>-1</span>` then the correct result is `extract_<span style="color: red">me</span>-1` but your result is `extract_<span style="color: red">me`.  Use an HTML parser.

Comment: @BenVoigt lol its not a bug, its a feature.. I think you're talking about tag nesting. Like I mentioned somewhere in the above comment, its not a complete html (so no parser), its just some random tags and I just  simply need text upto the next closest end tag. imagine if have``str=<span id='1'>hello</span>world</span>`` My expected output would be ```hello```

Comment: My initial comment was to use a html parser so I am obviously aware of the limitations.